# Is there a way to allow "undefined" hashes in params without permitting everything?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, parameters

I have a model that serializes a Hash called `current_values` as JSON in the database. The model looks like this:

```
class Template
  belongs_to :user
  serialize :current_values, JSON
  # has attributes title and description
  # ...
end
```

Now I want to create a new Template, and the controller looks like this:

```
class TemplateController < ApplicationController
  # ...
  def create
    template = Template.new(template_params)
    template.save
    # ...
  end

  private

  def template_params
    params.require(:template).permit(:title,
                                     :description,
                                     :current_values)
  end
  # ...
end
```

If I use this code with `params` that look like this:

```
"template" => {
  "title" => "title",
  "description" => "description",
  "current_values" => {
    "foo" => "foo",
    "bar" => "bar"
  }
}
```

I get this error message:

```
Unpermitted parameters: current_values
```

I have read the documentation for `permit` on http://api.rubyonrails.org/ but I cannot figure out how I can allow any value for `current_values` without allowing everything with `permit!`. I do not know which attributes will be in `current_values`, thus I cannot pass an array with the allowed attributes. and I do not want to allow everything because then someone could overwrite `:user_id`.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem you have to change the method:

```
def template_params
  params.require(:template).permit(:title,
                                   :description,
                                   :current_values)
end
```

to:

```
def template_params
  params.require(:template).permit(:title,
                                   :description).tap do |whitelisted|
    whitelisted[:current_values] = params[:template][:current_values]
  end
end
```